# Elegant way to check if a local group already exists

Tags: c#, .net, directoryentry

Is there a way to find out if a local group already exists? My "best" solution works by catching an exception. Is there a way to do achieve the same goal without catching an exception?

```
var machine = Environment.MachineName;
var server = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0},Computer", machine));
bool groupExists = true;
try
{
   server.Children.Find("MyGroup", "group");
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
   if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147022676)
      groupExists = false;
   else
      throw;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
        var machine = Environment.MachineName;
        var server = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0},Computer", machine));
        bool exists = server.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Any(d => d.SchemaClassName.Equals("Group") && d.Name.Equals("Administrators"));
```

Comment: how do we get users inside "Administrators" Group?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use the [PrincipalContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_) class as follows:

```
using(var local = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)) 
{
    var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(local, "MyGroup");
    var groupExists = group != null; 
}
```